# EdgeのWeb画面のボタンを押下した場合、C#側で、ボタンの押下処理を登録（検知、AddListener？）する方法をご教示願います。

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**質問内容**
C#でEdgeのWeb画面を制御するツールを開発しています。
EdgeのWeb画面のボタンを押下した場合、C#側で、ボタンの押下処理を登録（検知、AddListener？）する方法を教えて頂けますでしょうか？
（人がWeb画面のボタンを押下したら、常駐しているC#ツール側で、その押下処理を自動検知できる仕組みを実装することができますでしょうか？）

**問題背景**
C#でInternet explorer11のWeb画面のボタン押下は検知できています。
方法はmshtml.HTMLButtonElementEvents_Eventで、該当ボタンのOnclickイベントをC#側に登録しておくと、Web画面で該当ボタンが押下されたのを検知できます。

WebシステムのEdge移行に伴い、ツールもEdge対応が必要です。
現在、C#と「Selenium　WebDriver For Edge」の組み合わせで
C#ツール側でEdgeを新規起動し、該当Web画面を表示するまでは実装できました。
Edge上のWeb画面のボタン押下をトリガーに、データ取得＆C#画面表示などを実装しようとしているところです。
WebDriverではEdgeのWeb画面のボタンを登録（検知）できませんでした。
WebDriverを含め、他の部品でも「WebDriverではEdgeのWeb画面のボタンを登録（検知）する」方法をご教示頂きたいです。
  (Edgeはセキュリティが向上しているので、IE11のようにMicrosoft社の部品（API）でAddLIstenerは不可能でしょうか？)

**開発環境**
ＯＳ：Windows 10 　バージョン1803
ブラウザ：Edge(バージョン42)
.netFramwork 4.6.2
MS VisualStudio Pro 2017　C#

**利用環境**
ＯＳ：Windows 10 　バージョン1803
ブラウザ：Edge(バージョン42)
.netFramwork:4.6.2

Comment: この記事が参考になるかもしれません。[addEventListener handler function not returning all attributes of the event object for mouse click event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34260283/9014308)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。C#からEdgeブラウザのWeb画面に、Javascriptを文字列として、追加し、AddLIstenerを動作させることは可能でしたが、AddLIstenerの戻り値をC#側のObjectに紐付けができませんでした。続けて、試してみます。

Comment: そうしたらこのリポジトリが参考になるかも。[AbrahamSanders/Selenium.WebDriver.EventCapture](https://github.com/AbrahamSanders/Selenium.WebDriver.EventCapture) とそのページにいくつかのリンクがあります。そして目的には合ってないとされている EventFiringWebDriver関連はこちらでしょう。[Understanding WebDriver Events](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-webdriver-events-e58124575edd), [How to implement a WebDriverEventListener in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34678267/9014308), [WebDriverEventListener](http://design-ambience.com/blog/?p=368)

Comment: 回答、本当に有難うございます。更に確認したいですが、C # + Selenium.WebDriverで、既に開いているEdgeを検知（キャッチ？）して、そのDOMを特定し、要素のプロパティ（値、色、ID等）を取得するのは可能でしょうか？（WebDriverから開いたEdgeではなく）

Comment: 古くてC#でもEdgeでも無いですが、これらの記事を読み解くとできるかもしれません。[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8344776/9014308), [Is there any way to attach an already running browser to selenium webdriver in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11969893/9014308), [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861813/9014308), [How to connect Selenium to an existing browser that was opened manually?](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/)

Comment: なお、同様の質問に対して可否の両方の記事のあるサイトもあります。[Can we use Selenium to work with an already open browser session?](https://www.edureka.co/community/2170/can-we-use-selenium-to-work-with-already-open-browser-session), [Can Selenium webdriver attach to already open browser window?](https://www.edureka.co/community/22303/can-selenium-webdriver-attach-already-open-browser-window)

Comment: 返信が遅くなって申し訳ありません。いろいろ、情報のご提示ありがとうございます。もうちょっとお試ししてから、状況を報告させていただきます。

Comment: やりたいことが、このスレで質問した内容と変わってきたので、新しいスレを立てました。お手数をお掛けします。